# DisplayAlert within a Method Throws HandleTargetEvent: UnhandledException

Tags: c#, socket.io, xamarin.forms, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to call DisplayAlert from inside a method from a C# SocketIO library. No matter how I call DisplayAlert from inside the method, it always results in 'InspectorDebugSession(somenum): HandleTargetEvent: UnhandledException'. Even with the helper method to try and do it outside of the method technically, it still doesn't work. If I move the socket.On() to outside of the constructor and into another method where it would still fire, it still doesn't work.

```
public PhoneNumberPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        App.socket.On("code_status", async (data) =>
        {
            await DisplayAlert("hi", "hi", "hi");
            if (true)
            {
                await this.DisplayAlert("hi", "hi", "hi");
                displayAlert("hi", "hi", "hi");
            }
            if ((string)data == "timeout")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("!TIMEOUT!");
            }
            else if (!(bool)data)
            {
                displayAlert("Wrong Code", "The code you entered was incorrect!", "Ok");
            }
            else if ((bool)data)
            {
                // save
            }
        });
    }
private async void displayAlert(string title, string info, string accept, string cancel)
    {
        await DisplayAlert(title, info, accept, cancel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `App.socket.On` lambda callback is perhaps not on the UI thread.

Try:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await DisplayAlert("hi", "hi", "hi"));
```